# Android, Google Drive API. Folder search/insert java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to create new instance of class com.google.a.b.a.a.e

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive API in android app. It worked good when app was signed by debug.keystore. But if I sign it by production key I'm getting weird exceptions.

Code for searching and creating folders:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List request = 
    service.files().list()
        .setQ("'" + folderId + "' in parents " +
            "and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' " +
            "and trashed=false " +
            "and title='" + title + "'");
FileList files = request.execute();
if (files.getItems().size() == 0) {
    ParentReference parentReference = new ParentReference();
    parentReference.setId(folderId);
    parent.add(parentReference);
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(title);
    body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
    body.setParents(parent);
    File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();
    folderId = file.getId();
} else {
    folderId = files.getItems().get(0).getId();
}
```

FileList files = request.execute(); -- execute method gives exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to create new instance of
>   class com.google.a.b.a.a.e because it has no accessible default
>   constructor

So this part of code can't search and insert folders.
This exception appears **only when app is signed by production key**. With debug key it works perfect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Proguard was the reason of "no accessible default constructor"

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by
> removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with
> semantically obscure names.
>
> ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode

[ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: did you make changes to your proguard configuration to make this work?

Comment: I just disabled Proguard in project.properties file (#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project. -- this line is commented now). It was not good idea to disable it, but I didn't have to much time to play with proguard settings and test.

Comment: thanks. if you want to try it, this fixed a possibly similar issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15708989/426493