# Android: Integration with google drive sdk doesn't work in obfuscated build?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My app integrates with the google drive sdk.  It works as expected when running from eclipse, but with a build obfuscated with proguard, I get the below error.  The proguarded build is signed with a different keystore than the one from eclipse (which is signed with the debug keystore).  In my Google Apis Console I created 2 client IDs, each with the SHA1 from each keystore.

Is likely to be caused by some issue with proguard?  Any other suggestions?

```
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742): com.google.a.a.b.b.c: 403 Forbidden
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742): {
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):   "code": 403,
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):   "errors": [
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):     {
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):       "domain": "usageLimits",
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):       "message": "Access Not Configured",
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):     }
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):   ],
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742): }
03-29 15:08:50.845: E/error(24742):     at com.google.a.a.b.d.a.c.b(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by adding the below to my proguard config, found in the following link.   Given the error message, it was surprising this was an obfuscation issue.

```
-keep class com.google.** { *;}
-keep interface com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.**

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature
-keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
*;
}
-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {
*;
}
```

[Google Drive API doesn't play well with ProGuard (NPE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410520/google-drive-api-doesnt-play-well-with-proguard-npe)